# can't build max/msp external with onnx-runtime, "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol..."

Tags: visual-studio, linker-errors, onnxruntime, max-msp-jitter

i am trying to write a max-external to do inference on an .onnx neural network on. i have followed several tutorials on certain steps but fail to combine them:

i managed to create a c++ console app in vs that loads my .onnx model and runs inference
(seting up vs-project and importing onnxruntime via nuget taken from here: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/onnxruntime-opencv-for-c-b19ef189d3a8)

i managed to setup a vs-project with cmake that builds a working max-external (.mxe64)
(https://github.com/Cycling74/min-devkit/blob/main/HowTo-NewObject.md)

when i import the onnxruntime nuget into the solution i created with cmake, i get linker errors as soon as i try to include the onnxruntime_cxx_api.h

`` mmm.hello-world.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol OrtGetApiBase referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'public: static struct OrtApi const * const Ort::Global<void>::api_''(void)" (??__E?api_@?$Global@X@Ort@@2PEBUOrtApi@@EB@@YAXXZ) [C:\Users\misch\Documents\Max 8\Packages\mmm\source\projects\mmm.hello-world\mmm.hell o-world.vcxproj] ``

[screenshot of error msgs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73n0J.png)

i'd guess that this is just an issue of a missing path/directory somewhere but i have honestly no idea where to start there... i tried comparing the project properties between the two working tutorial projects but couldn't spot any notable differences.

appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction.